# как при добавлении фрагмента затемнять задний фон, чтобы фокус был на фрагменте?

Tags: android, android-fragment, design

Добавляю фрагмент(небольшую форму) по нажатии на floating action button, как при появлении фрагмента затемнять задний фон?

Comment: видимо вам нужно наследовать фрагмент от DialogFragment и вызывать его как диалог

Comment: @Jarvis_J попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если вы показываете что-то типа диалога тогда и пользуйтесь диалогами, не выдумывайте велосипед. Так же часто использую activity которой указывают тему диалога. В манифесте для диалоговой активити указываем

```
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/MyDialogStyle" />
```

В стилях указываем parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```